# AES-128-CBC algorithm: openssl_encrypt(): Using an empty Initialization Vector (iv) is potentially insecure and not recommended

Tags: laravel, openssl, aes, laravel-8, php-openssl

```
 public function encrypt($message){
        $sifrelememetodu = "AES-128-CBC"; 
        $benimsifrem = "birgul.091!birgul!"; 
        $sifresicozulen = openssl_encrypt($message, $sifrelememetodu, $benimsifrem);
        
       return $sifresicozulen;
    
         }     

 public function decrypt($message){
        $sifrelememetodu = "AES-128-CBC"; 
        $benimsifrem = "birgul.091!birgul!"; 
        $sifresicozulen = openssl_decrypt($message, $sifrelememetodu, $benimsifrem);
        return $sifresicozulen;
      }

$data = $this->encrypt("47380908767");
$data =$this->decrypt($data);
```

But encrypt function is giving error that:

> openssl_encrypt(): Using an empty Initialization Vector (iv) is
> potentially insecure and not recommended

Comment: CBC mode uses an initialization vector (16 bytes for AES). If you do not specify one (in the 5th parameter), [`openssl_encrypt()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) implicitly creates an IV that contains only `0x00` values. However, a static IV is insecure, which is why this warning is displayed.

Comment: The correct way is to generate a random IV during encryption. The IV is also needed for decryption, is not secret and is usually passed along with the ciphertext, e.g. concatenated.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the **openssl_encrypt**. You can find more information in PHP documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php)

You decrypt function:

```
public function decrypt($message){
    $sifrelememetodu = "AES-128-CBC"; 
    $benimsifrem = "birgul.091!birgul!"; 
    $sifresicozulen = openssl_decrypt($message, $sifrelememetodu, $benimsifrem);
    return $sifresicozulen;
}
```

The encrypt function will be:

```
public function encrypt($message){
    $sifrelememetodu = "AES-128-CBC"; 
    $benimsifrem = "birgul.091!birgul!"; 
    $sifresicozulen = openssl_encrypt($message, $sifrelememetodu, $benimsifrem);
    return $sifresicozulen;
}
```

Comment: Please don't advise a fixed IV for CBC mode: [Why is CBC with predictable IV considered insecure against chosen-plaintext attack?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/3883/18298). It must be unpredictable that is more than just random.